# Resize Image while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: c#

Hey guys, I have an image that I'm downloading from the internet and need to resize it to 1/4 of it's size while preserving its aspect ratio. Any ideas on how to do this easiest?

```
WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(imageURL);
WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();
Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream());

// Need to resize image here

Random rand = new Random();
string imageName = string.Format("{0:x}{1:x}", DateTime.Now.Ticks, rand.Next(0, 60400000));
if (webImage != null)
{
     webImage.Save(string.Format("c:\\{0}.jpg", imageName));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Marino - Actually that will make it 1/16 its size.

Comment: if you are talking about the area, then sure yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2, null, IntPtr.Zero);
image.Dispose();
```

Comment: I concur to make the area 1/4 we should divide by 2. Hopefully the op wanted the area 4 times smaller, not the byte size or some other measure :)

Comment: Yes, hopefully, though I don't know what bizarre compression algorithm would effect the image's aspect ratio. :P

Comment: there is such algorithm in our universe: if you want to fix the aspect ratio of some rectangular area of space-time -> distribution of density of matter affects the distortion of space time - and lines delimiting the original rectangle become curves with their lenght changing if matter changes... fortunately bitmaps are much easier :D

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember version 0.84 of WinZip had a bug where it would distort space-time when you used "Ultra" compression. It was slow, too.